# How can I join these select statements into a single query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have the following select statements below that each have their own inner join to another table based on the same client_id. How can I combine these into a single query? The fact that each already relies on a inner join to a different table is what is giving me trouble.
The desired results are to have all the columns from each SELECT statement output from a single query based on the one client_id.

```
DECLARE client_id INT
SET client_id = {placeholder}

SELECT 
    N.first_name,
    N.middle_name,
    N.last_name
FROM Name N WITH(NOLOCK)
LEFT OUTER JOIN NameLink C WITH(NOLOCK)
    ON N.name_id = C.name_id
WHERE C.client_id = @client_id

SELECT 
    A.street_name,
    A.house_num,
    A.city,
    A.state_id,
    A.zip,
    S.state
FROM Address A
INNER JOIN AddressLink C
    ON A.address_id = C.address_id
INNER JOIN State S
    ON A.state_id = S.state_id
WHERE C.client_id = @client_id

SELECT 
E.email 
FROM Email E
INNER JOIN EmailLink C
    ON E.email_id = C.email_id
WHERE C.client_id = @client_id

SELECT
    P.phone_num
FROM Phone P
INNER JOIN PhoneLink C
    ON P.phone_id = C.phone_id
WHERE C.client_id = @client_id
```

Comment: This is not MySQL but MS SQL (SQL Server) syntax. Edit the taglist.

Comment: "The fact that each already relies on a inner join to a different table is what is giving me trouble" - That is not a problem at all. You can join as many tables as you want in a single statement. The problem is that they don't seem to be ralated in any other way but by client_id, so that it doesn't make sense to combine them. Or how do you combine (join) two phone numbers with two email addresses? So it's not clear what you actually want. Sample data and expected result could help to make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

When you need to JOIN the output for 2 queries you'd use

```sql
WITH
cte1 AS ( { query 1 } ),
cte2 AS ( { query 2 } )
SELECT {columns list}
FROM cte1
JOIN cte2 ON { joining condition }
{ WHERE, GROUP BY and so on }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use multiple `CTE`'s, be sure to `SELECT` the `client_id` in each one then use the `client_id` for each `CTE` in a `JOIN` statement outside of the `CTE`:

```
DECLARE client_id INT
SET client_id = {placeholder}

WITH cteA AS (
SELECT 
    N.first_name,
    N.middle_name,
    N.last_name,
    C.client_id
FROM Name N WITH(NOLOCK)
LEFT OUTER JOIN NameLink C WITH(NOLOCK)
    ON N.name_id = C.name_id
WHERE C.client_id = @client_id
), cteB AS (
SELECT 
    A.street_name,
    A.house_num,
    A.city,
    A.state_id,
    A.zip,
    S.state,
    C.client_id
FROM Address A
INNER JOIN AddressLink C
    ON A.address_id = C.address_id
INNER JOIN State S
    ON A.state_id = S.state_id
WHERE C.client_id = @client_id
), cteC AS (
SELECT 
E.email,
C.client_id
FROM Email E
INNER JOIN EmailLink C
    ON E.email_id = C.email_id
WHERE C.client_id = @client_id
), cteD AS (
SELECT
    P.phone_num,
    C.client_id
FROM Phone P
INNER JOIN PhoneLink C
    ON P.phone_id = C.phone_id
WHERE C.client_id = @client_id
)
SELECT
    cteA.first_name,
    cteA.middle_name,
    cteA.last_name,
    cteB.street_name,
    cteB.house_num,
    cteB.city,
    cteB.state_id,
    cteB.zip,
    cteB.state,
    cteC.email,
    cteD.phone_num
FROM cteA
LEFT JOIN cteB ON cteA.client_id = cteB.client_id
LEFT JOIN cteC ON cteA.client_id = cteC.client_id
LEFT JOIN cteD ON cteA.client_id = cteD.client_id
```